# Tomcat 8.0.18 not receiving full request from client

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

We are using Apache Tomcat 8.0.18 as our web server.We are getting expected output when the client is sending about 5 to 8 concurrent requests.

But when the client is sending about 30 to 40 concurrent request , client is getting some unexpected error related to some packet loss while the request reaching the web server hosted in tomcat through Internet.

We are not facing the issue while we testing the application in our local environment.

We have examined the web server logs and we are seeing only part of the requests are reaching the web servers. We have installed the Tomcat 8.0.18 with default configuration.

Can any one please guide us whether we need to change any configuration in Tomcat level to resolve this kind of packet loss issue?

Thanks
Dinesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you should install a packet sniffer on the host where Tomcat is installed. Maybe the problem doesn't come from tomcat.